# Java library for async 'multipart-form' file upload?

Tags: java, asynchronous, post, multipart, asynchttpclient

I am trying to upload a file (and additional fields) using single REST POST request. This request has to be processed **asynchronous** and form has to be submitted using **multipart-form** content type (because beside file I am sending few other text fields with certain metadata).

I tried with Apache's **org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClient** but until now I didn't succeed (when request arrives on the server, fields from the form are not presented). When I do the same using **org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient** request is processed without problems, so the issue is not on the server side.

Does anybody know how this async 'multipart-form' request could be made? If not possible with CloseableHttpAsyncClient, do you have some other library to suggest?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: i have similiar issue and it suprise me that async client doesn't support multi-from post.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to give an update. I did some investigation and was able to fulfill my requirements with [AsyncHttpClient (AHC)](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client)

It works very fast and is based on Netty Framework and NIO Java API.